# Async/Await not working as expected with gRPC method

Tags: javascript, typescript, grpc-node

this is the code to initialize a gRPC server I am using:

```
export const initServer = async (finalPort: number): Promise<string> => {
  let initStatus = 'initial';
  gRPCserver.addService(webcomponentHandler.service, webcomponentHandler.handler);

  // define the host/port for server
  await gRPCserver.bindAsync(
    `localhost:${finalPort}`,
    grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure(),
    (err: Error | null, port1: number) => {
      if (err != null) {
        console.error(err);
        log.info('Biding Error');
        initStatus = 'Binding Error';
      }
      // start the gRPC server
      gRPCserver.start();
      log.info(`startServer::gRPC server started, on port: ${port1}`);
      initStatus = 'OK';
    },
  );
  return initStatus;
};
```

I am trying to return that initStatus to this function:

```
type StartServerType = () => Promise<string | undefined>;
export const startServer: StartServerType = async (): Promise<string | undefined> => {
  try {
    let initStatusResponse;
    // Get port
    const finalPort = port();
    await server.initServer(finalPort).then((res) => {
      initStatusResponse = res;
      log.info('INIT STATUS RESPONSE: ', initStatusResponse);
    });
  } catch (e: unknown) {
    if (typeof e === 'string') {
      return e.toUpperCase(); // works, `e` narrowed to string
    }
    if (e instanceof Error) {
      return e.message; // works, `e` narrowed to Error
    }
  }
  return 'started';
};
```

But I always received 'initial' as initStatusResponse. I know there is an async issue there, but I can not see where.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in my experience, a function that takes a callback rarely returns a Promise - so `await gRPCserver.bindAsync.....` is unlikely to works as you want

Comment: I agree, `bindAsync` takes a callback function, therefore it doesn't return a Promise, so `await`ing it is pointless. The next line of code (`return initStatus;`) will execute immediately, before `initStatus` is set.

Comment: to be clear `async` `await` works with Promises, not anything vaguely asynchronous

Comment: Also, you are mixing `await` and the `.then()` syntax together. You can't use both at the same time, get rid of `.then()` entirely.

Comment: @JeremyThille - not true, you can mix the two - it's just not good practice :p

Comment: Okay you _can_, it doesn't crash or anything, but awaiting something that doesn't return a Promise is pointless. Let's say you _shouldn't_.

Comment: I never said anything about you can await something that doesn't return a promsie ... I was referring to your "mixing of await and .then" remark - because of course you can do that -since `.then` returns a Promise - Put it this way, I have one piece of code that does mix the two - because trying to use just `await` makes the code messy, and just using `.then` makes a bit of callback hell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to check the documentation for `gRPCserver.bindAsync` but it would seem that this method does not return a promise object. The likelihood of this is increased because you are passing a callback function as an argument. Promise objects remove the need for callback functions (Often referred to as "callback hell"). [Here is an article](https://stackify.com/async-javascript-approaches/) that explains the differences between the different ways to do asynchronous actions in Javascript/Typescript.

Using async/await is a good approach. In order to use it if `gRPCserver.bindAsync` doesn't return a promise we can "wrap" it in a promise. This can be done easily with the node.js util `promisify` ([Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)) or manually with `new Promise`. [This article](https://zellwk.com/blog/converting-callbacks-to-promises/) explains both ways well.